# JS function onclick is not working. It is not calling validations

Tags: javascript, html

Below is function and it is not working. Maybe some small bug in the code which I am unable to identify.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function check(){
  firstname=document.getelementById("firstname").value;
  lastname=document.getelementById("lastname").value;
  if(lastname==""){
    alert('please enter lastname');
  }
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="check();">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" ><br>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" ><br>
            <input type="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive, hence there should be an error in the console -> `.getElementById()`

Comment: Press F12 to open your browser's debugging tools.  When you click the button, are there any errors on the browser console?  Is the page re-loading entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in the code: case sensitive getelEmentById. Please below code and test it

```
function check(){
  firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  lastname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  if(lastname==""){
    alert('please enter lastname');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GetElementById, element with a capital E 
JavaScript is case sensive.
TIP: use developer options in your browser. They usualy give an error message.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function check(){
  firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  lastname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  if(lastname==""){
    alert('please enter lastname');
  }
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="check();">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" ><br>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" ><br>
            <input type="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```